# dynamic array size from number of lines in a file

Tags: c++, arrays

I have made an array, but now its size needs to be determined by the number of lines in a file, it works fine until I use the for loop to put the array elements in to another file, I get the error " _Pnext is 0xCCCCCCD0", why is that? If I put a number i.e. 30 in the for loop instead of number_of_lines, its works fine

```
int number_of_lines=0;
std::string line2;
std::ifstream myfile("Input_files\\Pronunciations.txt");
while (std::getline(myfile, line2))
{
    ++number_of_lines;
}
string *hexsource = new string[number_of_lines];
for (int o = 0; o <number_of_lines; ++o)
{
    file2 >> name[o] >> ipaname[o] >> anyway[o];
}
```

Comment: Use `std::vector<std::string>`. And don't `new std::string`, it's a value type, use it as such.

Comment: `o <++number_of_lines` seems suspicious.

Comment: `hexsource` is unused, and we don't have declaration of `file2`, `name`, `ipaname` and `anyway`.

Comment: They are declared before this part of the code, and hexsource is used after this. If I put a number i.e. 30 in the for loop instead of number_of_lines, its works fine. Why doesnt number_of_lines works? If i cout number_of_lines its 301

Comment: I don't want to be that guy, but can't help myself. This would be a oneliner in Python (`[line.split() for line in open('filename.txt')]`), with an additional six characters if you necessarily want to fetch the data in columns instead of rows. Have you considered using Python instead?

Comment: @JonasByström This is a one (or 2) liner in C++ also.

Comment: @Znap -- What is `name`, `ipaname`, and `anyway`?  You just introduced these variables out of thin air.  Please post a [mcve].  How do you know if these arrays are sized properly?

Comment: You need to use vector<std::string>, if you want use new string[] after that you need release memory by []delete

Comment: Yes i did that at the end of the code,  after i finished using hexsource[]

Comment: @Znap -- Is [something like this](http://ideone.com/nc6JdU) what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure that the problem is within the loop?
if that is so, the one problem i can think about is that if number_of_lines is greater than than the size of name/ipname/anyway , it'll create a problem.

What size have you given to these?

And what is the value maximum value of number_of_lines?

You need to mention every required thing in your code

Comment: The value of number_of_lines is 302, and the texts in the file are being loaded into string hexsource[number_of_lines] . If in the for loop i say for (int o = 0; o < 302; ++o), it then works fine

Comment: Well if by changing ONLY number_of_lines to 302, your program is running fine, that just goes to say that the value to number_of_lines is greater than 302

Comment: Add a line : 
"std::cout<<number_of_lines<<endl;"
Before the for loop to confirm

Comment: Thanks, this loop counted the end line twice, but dont know why.....  If I use this method to count the number of lines, it then works 
` myfile.unsetf(std::ios_base::skipws);

 
 unsigned line_count = std::count(
  std::istream_iterator<char>(myfile),
  std::istream_iterator<char>(),
  '\n');`

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int o = 0; o <++number_of_lines; ++o)
```

should probably be

```
for (int o = 0; o < number_of_lines; ++o)
```

Else your end condition is never met.

Comment: Sorry i made a very stupid typo here, it wasnt o <++number_of_lines, just o < number_of_lines. So its not that